# iOS Image rotates on button press

Tags: ios

I am downloading some images from an API to my ios app and then displaying the images as a button background. Here's the code:

```
NSData *imageData = [r responseData]; 
UIImage *image =  [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];               
UIBlockButton *imageView = [UIBlockButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];       
[imageView setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Here's the weird part. Vertical images (Length is less than height) will rotate 90 degrees when I press the button. Has anyone experienced this before/is it a bug?

Edit: So my server sends the images in the rotated state. Somehow the UIButton knows to rotate it when it is not selected, but doesn't make the same correction when I select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `[imageView setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];`

Unless, of course, you prefer another image for the highlighted state to simulate the actual pressing of the button. In that case you will use the other Image in/instead of "image".

But you should get rid of that strange effect at least.

Comment: Thanks. I did that. I guess I'm asking the question more to see if anyone knows why it happens.

Comment: Frankly I don't know why. It just came to my mind because I saw other strange things happen when the image for highlight state was not set. On reason could be that your downloaded image contains some EXIF data with an orientation tag set to portrait. But in that case you could ask why it was not rotated in normal state. :)

Comment: For me, this causes the bug to occur slightly less often, but it still happens about half the time. Another strange datapoint: when the buttons are first shown, this code causes the image to display correctly when highlighted. Only after the parent view disappears then reappears does the bug occur (and again, only half the time). Bizarre.